# iText 7 Html to Pdf conversion and linking external file to the generated pdf

Tags: java, pdf, itext, html-to-pdf

I am encountering an issue while merging two PDFs generated out of IText.
I am new to iText7
I am creating one pdf from html and creating another pdf with excel(.xls) as embedded document to pdf.
I want to merge the 2 files.

Basically I want to generate a PDF from html then attach a excel document to it and then output combined html outPutStream from these two pdfs.

Below is the code I am using

```
    ByteArrayOutputStream htmlToPdfContent = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(htmlToPdfContent);
    PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
    pdf.setTagged();
    PageSize pageSize = PageSize.A4.rotate();
    pdf.setDefaultPageSize(pageSize);
    ConverterProperties properties = new ConverterProperties();
    HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(htmlContent, pdf, properties);

    FileUtils.cleanDirectory(new File(outputDir));

    ByteArrayOutputStream pdfResult = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    PdfWriter writerResult = new PdfWriter(pdfResult);
    PdfDocument pdfDocResult = new PdfDocument(writerResult);

    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(htmlToPdfContent.toByteArray()));
    PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(reader);
    pdfDoc.copyPagesTo(1, pdfDoc.getNumberOfPages(), pdfDocResult);

    ByteArrayOutputStream pdfAttach = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    PdfDocument pdfLaunch = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(pdfAttach));
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(36, 700, 100, 100);
    byte[] embeddedFileContentBytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(excelPath));
    PdfFileSpec fs = PdfFileSpec.createEmbeddedFileSpec(pdfLaunch, embeddedFileContentBytes, null, "test.xlsx", null, null);
    PdfAnnotation attachment = new PdfFileAttachmentAnnotation(rect, fs)
            .setContents("Click me");
    pdfLaunch.addNewPage().addAnnotation(attachment);

    PdfDocument appliedChanges = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(pdfAttach.toByteArray())));

    appliedChanges.copyPagesTo(1, appliedChanges.getNumberOfPages(), pdfDocResult);
    try(OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(dest)) {
        pdfResult.writeTo(outputStream);
    }
```

This is throwing exception

```
13:56:05.724 [main] ERROR com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfReader - Error occurred while reading cross reference table. Cross reference table will be rebuilt.
com.itextpdf.io.IOException: Error at file pointer 19,272.
    at com.itextpdf.io.source.PdfTokenizer.throwError(PdfTokenizer.java:678)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfReader.readXrefSection(PdfReader.java:801)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfReader.readXref(PdfReader.java:774)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfReader.readPdf(PdfReader.java:538)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument.open(PdfDocument.java:1818)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument.<init>(PdfDocument.java:238)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument.<init>(PdfDocument.java:221)
    at com.mediaocean.prisma.order.command.infrastructure.pdf.itext.PdfAttachmentLaunch.main(PdfAttachmentLaunch.java:76)
Caused by: com.itextpdf.io.IOException: xref subsection not found.
    ... 8 common frames omitted
Exception in thread "main" com.itextpdf.kernel.PdfException: Trailer not found.
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfReader.rebuildXref(PdfReader.java:1064)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfReader.readPdf(PdfReader.java:543)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument.open(PdfDocument.java:1818)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument.<init>(PdfDocument.java:238)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument.<init>(PdfDocument.java:221)
    at com.mediaocean.prisma.order.command.infrastructure.pdf.itext.PdfAttachmentLaunch.main(PdfAttachmentLaunch.java:88)
13:56:05.773 [main] ERROR com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfReader - Error occurred while reading cross reference table. Cross reference table will be rebuilt.
com.itextpdf.io.IOException: PDF startxref not found.
    at com.itextpdf.io.source.PdfTokenizer.getStartxref(PdfTokenizer.java:262)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfReader.readXref(PdfReader.java:753)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfReader.readPdf(PdfReader.java:538)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument.open(PdfDocument.java:1818)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument.<init>(PdfDocument.java:238)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument.<init>(PdfDocument.java:221)
    at com.mediaocean.prisma.order.command.infrastructure.pdf.itext.PdfAttachmentLaunch.main(PdfAttachmentLaunch.java:88)
```

Please advise. Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 0):

#### Concerning [revision 2 of your question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/63483151/2)

You changed your code differently than proposed in my answer to the first revision of your question, you now convert into the formerly unused `PdfDocument pdf` instead of directly into the `ByteArrayOutputStream htmlToPdfContent`.

This actually also is a possible fix of the problem identified in that answer. Thus, you don't get an exception here anymore:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(htmlToPdfContent.toByteArray()));
PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(reader);
```

Instead you now get an exception further down the flow, here:

```
PdfDocument appliedChanges = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(pdfAttach.toByteArray())));
```

And the reason is simple, you have not yet closed the `PdfDocument pdfLaunch` which writes to the `ByteArrayOutputStream pdfAttach`. But only closing finalizes the PDF in the output stream. Thus, add the `close()`:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream pdfAttach = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PdfDocument pdfLaunch = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(pdfAttach));
[...]
pdfLaunch.addNewPage().addAnnotation(attachment);
pdfLaunch.close(); //<==== added

PdfDocument appliedChanges = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(pdfAttach.toByteArray())));
```

And you actually do the same mistake again, shortly after, you store the contents of the `ByteArrayOutputStream pdfResult` to `outputStream` without closing the `PdfDocument pdfDocResult` which writes to `pdfResult`. Thus, also add a `close` call there:

```
appliedChanges.copyPagesTo(1, appliedChanges.getNumberOfPages(), pdfDocResult);
pdfDocResult.close(); //<==== added
try(OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(dest)) {
    pdfResult.writeTo(outputStream);
}
```

#### Concerning [revision 1 of your question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/63483151/1)

You use the `ByteArrayOutputStream htmlToPdfContent` as target of two distinct PDF generators, the `PdfDocument pdf` via the `PdfWriter writer` and the `HtmlConverter.convertToPdf` call:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream htmlToPdfContent = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(htmlToPdfContent);
PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
pdf.setTagged();
PageSize pageSize = PageSize.A4.rotate();
pdf.setDefaultPageSize(pageSize);
ConverterProperties properties = new ConverterProperties();
HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(content, htmlToPdfContent, properties);
```

This makes the content of `htmlToPdfContent` a hodgepodge of the outputs of both of them, in particular not a valid PDF.

As you don't add any content to `pdf`, you can safely remove it and reduce the above excerpt to

```
ByteArrayOutputStream htmlToPdfContent = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ConverterProperties properties = new ConverterProperties();
HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(content, htmlToPdfContent, properties);
```

Comment: I had used that code because I wanted pdf in landscape mode. So to rotate I passed the pdf instance to writer
I made the suggested change and getting error in line 
`PdfDocument appliedChanges = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(pdfAttach.toByteArray())));
`
getting this error  : PDF startxref not found/com.itextpdf.kernel.PdfException: Trailer not found.

Comment: Also is it possible to add excel as attachment in HtmlToPdfConverter?

Comment: *"Also is it possible to add excel as attachment in HtmlToPdfConverter?"* - I don't know. I doubt it but I don't use html-to-pdf conversions myself, so I'm not into `HtmlToPdfConverter` details...

Comment: @NeerajKunturkar by the way, is there a reason why your code so often serializes the PDFs, reads them anew, and copies their pages to the next `PdfDocument`? Your code could be considerably shorter, saver, and faster by not doing so...

Comment: I have shortened the code and reduced serialization and serializations.
Now I am able to attach launch link at the end of generated pdf. Thanks 

But with my implementation I am adding annotation on new page.. `pdfLaunch.addNewPage().addAnnotation(attachment);`
 Instead of this can I add this launch link at existing line in the PDF. Something like:
`
TEXT......
.......
Please click here (link to launch)
.......
.......
`
Add a placeholder for the link when creating PDF at the first time and then
Launch to link is edited with actual data to be attached?

Comment: As mentioned above, I don't know whether there is an option to do this immediately in `HtmlToPdfConverter`. But what you can do, of course, is to apply text+position extraction to the generated PDF, look for "Please click here (link to launch)" in the result, and add the annotation right there.

Comment: Thanks!
I tried but I could not find solution. As I am new to Itext @mkl can you please suggest sudo algo or any samples. Thanks!